# Ubuntu 14.04 does not boot

Tags: boot, 14.04, ati, bootloader

Can you please help me, after performing system updates on Ubuntu 14.04.1, my laptop does not boot, only blank screen. I have tried using repair disk but no joy.
My file is :  http://paste.ubuntu.com/8310674

Comment: Does it boot until Grub? If so, what happens when you hit `Ctrl+Alt+F1` after it loads Linux?

Comment: yes, it boots until grub but that's it, nothing else, tried many things but nothing. I just want to reverse to ubuntu default graphics instead of amd

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is the proprietary graphics drivers are causing the problem, try to reinstall the operating system. I had the same problem and then I switched to open source graphic drivers already included in the ubuntu operating system.

Comment: Hi fm21, I had the open source graphic drivers after installation but I installed Catalyst (AMD) because my laptop was overheating easily when watching videos but after a system update, it is not booting anymore, do you know how to change to the open source without re-installing the whole system? Thanks

Comment: or the hard disk is gone!

Comment: you should report the error in launchpad page of ubuntu